# What anime with "four godly kings" is referenced by Seitokai Yakuindomo in episode 2?

Tags: seitokai-yakuindomo

In the second episode of [Seitokai Yakuindomo](http://myanimelist.net/anime/8675/Seitokai_Yakuindomo), at around the 12 minute mark, Shino Amakusa is referencing different animes. She says, at one point,

> "how about a fiancé who's sword dancing outside of the party grounds"

which makes it pretty obvious she's probably talking about [Princess Lover!](http://myanimelist.net/anime/6201/Princess_Lover). However, before that, she mentions

> "maybe the one where the antagonist was defeated, but it turns out that he was the first pupil of the four godly kings"

to which Aria Shichijou responds with

> "you have to provide a glimpse of the last boss, too"

And I have no idea which anime they're referencing to. What is the name of the anime with the antagonist and the four godly kings?

Comment: Not too sure but when I hear four heavenly kings only Sailor Moon comes to mind.